# how to repeat alarm after 1 day in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I m using the alarm manager in my app and i want to repeat alarm after one day. the alarm should be invoked after one day when invoked once by time.Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
if(str_freqSchedule.equals(checkForDaily)){
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this.getApplicationContext(), j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),(24*60*60*1000),pendingIntent);
            j++;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully below code will help, I used the same in my app. Here the argument passed in AlarmManager class for repeating should be 24*60*60*1000

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);         
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ct, TimeAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Date curr=new Date();
curr.setHours(h);
curr.setMinutes(m);
c.setTime(curr);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: instead of hard code manipulation (24*60*60*1000) you can use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY. Check this for different interval upto 1 day http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY

Comment: my alarm is invoking continuously till time period not expires,for example 12.12. then it is invoking continuously till time becomes 12.13.

Comment: INTERVAL_DAY running on Android prior to API 19 Only. @pratik

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use inexactrepeating instead of setExactRepeating keeping in mind of battery consumption as per android documentation.

```
      public void scheduleAlarms(AlarmManager mgr, PendingIntent pi, Context context) 
                {

                    // every day at scheduled time 
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                   // if it's after or equal 9 am schedule for next day
                   if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 9) {
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); 
                    }
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

              mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);         
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ct, TimeAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, yourtime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: does alarm receiver activity(Broadcast receiver) returns the control to the method where alarm was scheduled?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(HomeContactActivity.this,
        AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        HomeContactActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// Set the alarm to start at 10:00 AM
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);




manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, // for repeating in every 24 hours
        pendingIntent);
```